# iphone:SIGABRT when i append NSMutable Array

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray

When I append `NSMutableArray` with some constant name it shows an error of SIGABRT..

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[self.Plist objectAtIndex: indexPath.row] valueForKey: NAME_KEY];
```

Comment: Can you post how `NAME_KEY` is defined and how `self.Plist` is initialized?

Comment: i made one plist with dictionary type items and the item categories are the same like name,directions nd so on so i made one header file which contains constans values like #define NAME_KEY @"name"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to make sure that - 
a) NSDictionary is added to your Plist array before you could use valueForKey:
b) The value you added to dictionary is of type NSSting
 - Else you would get this SIGABRT's.

I would suggest before adding the "value" to your cell.text.label store in your temp variable and check for the correct value type.

Comment: @shweta - was the previous message any helpful?